# Using flexbox why two images with different proportions stretch differently

Tags: css, image, flexbox, responsive

I want to make a flexbox grid for cards with one big image on left and two right images vertically aligned. Everything is fine and aligned for desktop at 1280px but when images stretch for responsive view, the image on the left is stretching more rapidly and cards are no more vertically aligned.

Here a codepen illustrating the problem: 
https://codepen.io/actik/pen/xaZqmG

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.row {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.col {
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.structure-100 {
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.structure-50 {
  flex: 1 50%;
}

.content {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #aa0000;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.element_left {
  flex: 1 50%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.element_right {
  flex: 1 50%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.content-text {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="flex row structure-100">     

        <div class="flex col structure-50">    
            <div class="flex element_left">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/625/875/" alt="">
                    <div class="content-text">
                      <h2>Card title</h2>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum lacus vitae aliquam ullamcorper.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="flex col structure-50">

            <div class="flex element_right">
              <div class="content">
                <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/625/360" alt="">
                <div class="content-text">
                  <h2>Card title</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum lacus vitae aliquam ullamcorper.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex element_right">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/625/360" alt="">
                    <div class="content-text">
                      <h2>Card title</h2>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum lacus vitae aliquam ullamcorper.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I made a lot of different tests and can't understand this behavior, any tips welcome, thanks for your help !

Editing : Here the version at 1280px working (title cards are aligned at the bottom) and the second version when reducing width, bottom of the 2 images and title cards are no more aligned. I want the red part add space at his bottom if necessary but keep image and title aligned.

[working version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObyaF.png)
[not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD8XG.png)

[Big image is squashed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNGoC.png)

Comment: try to use `media queries` to allow responsiveness to the breakpoints you'll make.

Comment: i will use media queries for phone size but for large screen this is not a media query problem the flexbox container must stretch, perhaps my problem is not clear ?

Comment: yes, you're issue isn't that clear. I suggest you make at least 3 breakpoints: for small devices as mobile phones, medium devices as tablets, large devices.

Comment: Thanks for your help, ok,i'll try to be more clear : if you reduce the browser width on the codepen you will see that when you are under the 1280px container size, for exemple 1100px, the left card is no more aligned to the bottom of the right card. All the red block are the same height so this come from the image stretching, not a media query problem. Is this helps ?

Comment: check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from our talk in the comments, your issue that the left section with the 'big' image (the images aren't present in the snippet you provided, they're present in the CodePen demo that tou do provided its link) isn't stretching as supposed, and that because in your`CSS` you gave the  `.flex` class a rule of `align-items: flex-start;` which means that the element of the flex container should be placed on the top (vertical), thus, it doesn't let the element to stretch, instead, you just have to replace this line `align-items: flex-start;` with `align-items: stretch;` in the `.flex` class, so that class becomes:

```css
.flex {
   display: flex;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   align-items: stretch;
}
```

And here's a runnable snippet:

```css
$gutter: 30px;

.wrap{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.row {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.col {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.structure-100 {
    flex: 1 percentage(1/1);
}

.structure-50 {
    flex: 1 percentage(1/2);
}

.content {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #aa0000;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1 100%; 
  }
.element_left .content {
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  }
.element_left {
    flex: 1 percentage(1/2);
    padding-right: $gutter / 2;
    padding-bottom: $gutter;
}
    
.element_right {
    flex: 1 percentage(1/2);
    padding-left: $gutter / 2;
    padding-bottom: $gutter;
}

.content-text {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.element_left .content .content-text {
  flex-grow: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
}
.element_left .content img {
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="flex row structure-100">     

        <div class="flex col structure-50">    
            <div class="flex element_left">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/625/875/" alt="">
                    <div class="content-text">
                      <h2>Card title</h2>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum lacus vitae aliquam ullamcorper.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="flex col structure-50">

            <div class="flex element_right">
              <div class="content">
                <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/625/360" alt="">
                <div class="content-text">
                  <h2>Card title</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum lacus vitae aliquam ullamcorper.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex element_right">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/625/360" alt="">
                    <div class="content-text">
                      <h2>Card title</h2>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum lacus vitae aliquam ullamcorper.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: Thanks for your time on this, yes it's better but image is still not aligned when you reduce width, the red part is growing in height. I have modified the codepen with "align-items: stretch;" so you can see the result with images. (i don't know why images are not displayed on the snippet version so please take the codepen as reference). Perhaps i have to add a flex property on ".content-text" div with appropriate stretch property ?

Comment: can you, please, provide a screenshot so i could figure what the problem is.

Comment: i've edited my question with 2 screenshots working version and not working.

Comment: Thank you again, that's almost perfect but now the image is not aligned on top with the image at his right. I don't understand why the big image is not filling all the space of his container. I've updated the codepen with your suggestion so you can see the result.

Comment: @actik check the answer, i updated it, now everything should be perfect.

Comment: I'm sorry, i've made your correction on the codepen but the big image is not aligned on his bottom, can you see this ? do i missed something ?

Comment: i see. I think your goal isn't reachable with this markup. Try to refactor it and let me know.

Comment: Perhaps the red block must have a fixed height so the image can fill his container ?

Comment: @actik i updated my answer check out the runnable sniipet, but it may not work qs intended so copy it to codepen.

Comment: Wow ths seems to work ! I will check your solution in detail. Thanks so much for your time and effort ;)

Comment: @actik you're welcome, just let me hear if that satisfies you.

Comment: one last thing, when reducing the big image is squished. Any ideas of how I can keep the image in its original aspect ratio?

Comment: if you can give me a screenshot of this behaviour.

Comment: i've added a screenshot where you can see that the big image is squashed.

Comment: See, its all about responsivness ! Remember when i told you to use `media-queries` ? Imagine you have a breakpoint of let's say 768px from here and less the left and right sections become on top of each other, that will give the images more space. In fact, what you are facing is the normal behaviour, the space that did the 'big' image take is small for it so it gets squashed.

Comment: ok i see the point, i will check that and add breakpoints. Thanks again for your help, really appreciate this.